# debug_print_backtrace doesn't work

Tags: php, wordpress, debug-backtrace

I have PHP 5.3.4 and when I try to use debug_print_backtrace, I don't get anything. When I use vardump, I get an empty array, as you can see below.

index.php:

```
<?php
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

require('./wp-blog-header.php');

var_dump(debug_backtrace());

echo PHP_VERSION;
?>
```

which returns

```
...
</html> 
array(0) {
}
5.3.4
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong? I am expecting to see everything that was called in the run. Instead I don't see anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

debug_backtrace() doesn't show you what has been called so far but the current call stack (i.e. more or less where php would jump to on a `return` statement until it reaches the top level) when the function is invoked.
You might be interested in a profiler like e.g. the one implemented in [XDebug](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler) plus something to analyse the data like e.g. [kcachegrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html).

Comment: If you're in the very first PHP document loaded by your application, i.e. not in a function or include file, you can echo `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` to output the current file name and line number.

Comment: For anyone seeing this page when using it properly and still not getting expected results: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252529/get-code-line-and-file-thats-executing-the-current-function-in-php

Answer (score 2):

If you're really after Code Coverage (which it sounds like from your description) then XDebug is useful, or see the [responses to this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348850/code-coverage-tools-for-php)