# Laravel 5.2 - Get current line of Log event

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to custom my Logger in Laravel 5.2

For example, I have a Controller name `HomeController.php`:

```
class HomeController extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        Log::error("Ahihi");
    }
}
```

and the Log file:

`[2016-08-19 12:24:02] local.ERROR: Ahihi [] []`

but I want to log full the infomation of log event (like line in file):

`[2016-08-19 12:24:02] local.ERROR: HomeController.php - line 5 - Ahihi [] []`

I need some advices, thank you!

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252529/get-code-line-and-file-thats-executing-the-current-function-in-php

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have this kind of information in the message you log, you could use one of PHP's predefined constants - you can find a list here http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

The ones you might be most interested in are **__FILE__** and **__LINE__** that contain the name of current file and the current line number.

In order to achieve what you need you could replace

```
Log::error("Ahihi");
```

with

```
Log::error(sprintf("%s - line %d - Ahihi", __FILE__, __LINE__));
```

Comment: I also thinked about this but I want to implement for all Log::error(), this way can solve the problem but it will be terrible if I change the template.

Comment: Then you'll need to provide your own LogWriter implementation that would append this information to all log messages. I'll update the answer in a few hours with the example.